# Folium & Series object has not attribute get_name

Tags: python, folium

I'm pretty new to folium and faced an `AttributeError` while trying to add a series of markers to a `folium` map by looping through a pandas `df` containing coordinate pairs and the location name for each pair, e.g.

```
   location_name  location  
   'foo'          [40.736932, -73.997043]   
   'bar'          [40.738859, -73.995058]   
   'xyz'          [40.744085, -74.000394]
```

with the following code:

```
center_map = [40.738859, -73.995058]

map_1 = folium.Map(location=center_map, tiles=None, zoom_start=12)

for i in df:
        folium.Marker(i.location,
                      popup=i.location_name,
                      icon=folium.Icon(color='purple')
                      ).add_to(map_1)
```

However, I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'get_name'`

that I think is caused by the `element.py` and `generic.py` files in `folium`:

```
/Users/martin/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/folium/element.py in add_children(self, child, name, index)
     85     def add_children(self, child, name=None, index=None):
     86         """Add a child."""
---> 87         return self.add_child(child, name=name, index=index)
     88 
     89     def add_child(self, child, name=None, index=None):

/Users/martin/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/folium/element.py in add_child(self, child, name, index)
     90         """Add a child."""
     91         if name is None:
---> 92             name = child.get_name()
     93         if index is None:
     94             self._children[name] = child

/Users/martin/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   2667             if name in self._info_axis:
   2668                 return self[name]
-> 2669             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   2670 
   2671     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'get_name'
```

Appreciate any help on how to get around this!

Comment: If you add the multi line trace back also to the question one might directly have the files and lines exposed where - stack wise - the exception occured. My guess would be, that some magic background method / function expects its client objects to provide a get_name method to retrieve well a text that it then is able to print as string in some map or into a tooltip popup.

Comment: Why `for i in df:` and in the next line you try to add the full columns to `Marker`. Perhaps you want something like `for row in df: folium.Marker(row['location'], popup=row['location_name'], ...)`?

Comment: You're right, type-o from my end - sorry for confusion! I edited the code but am now getting `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Better late than never! Arrived here after the same error code, I had forgot to call folium.Popup(details) I suppose that's the child that's needed.

Error caused by this line

```
popup=i.location_name
```

which should be

```
popup = folium.Popup(i.location_name)
```